# Insertion time in arrays and linked lists

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Why are linked lists said to have O(1) insertion and deletion time, while arrays are said to have O(n) time for these operations?

To insert an element into a linked list, do we not have to examine all elements before it in order to find where to insert, taking O(n) time?

Comment: Who is "he"? Please be more specific

Comment: Sorry, I mean the writer says.

Comment: Which writer? That's not very helpful

Comment: I think what is meant is: If we store a List in an array (the naive way)  we would need O(n) but in a linked list we just need O(1).

Comment: The writer of "grokking algorithms" book, but anyway it doesn't matter who's the writer. Why O(1) though if we take insertion at position 5 as an example, we need to move from the first to second to third and so on until index number 5. so isn't it O(n) in this case?  thanks in advance :)

Comment: You've describing search (O(n)) followed by insert (O(1)). In an array, searching is O(1) and inserting is O(n). If you already have a reference to the node you're inserting after, insertion is O(1). If you don't, you are correct that you have to search for it first, which takes O(n) operations. Usually, insertion and deletion in a linked list takes place at either of its ends (for stacks and/or queues), in which case the operations are O(1) time.

Answer (score 1):

If a node be something like this in `c`

```
// A linked list Node
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Insert a new node on the front of the linked list is as below!

```c
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  
    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;
  
    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
  
    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}
```

You can see there is no loop and no need to traverse list, because we have a pointer to insertion location (which is front or end of list).
See [Linked List Inserting a node](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/) for more reference.

Insert an element at a specific position in an Array means something like this:
[image: see this]
Below is a C Program to Insert an element at a specific position in an Array, which need about `n/2` operation equal to complexity `o(n)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[100] = { 0 };
    int i, x, pos, n = 10;

    // initial array of size 10
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = i + 1;

    // print the original array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // element to be inserted
    x = 50;

    // position at which element
    // is to be inserted
    pos = 5;

    // increase the size by 1
    n++;

    // shift elements forward
    for (i = n-1; i >= pos; i--)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];

    // insert x at pos
    arr[pos - 1] = x;

    // print the updated array
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

See [Insert an element in an Array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-to-insert-an-element-in-an-array/) for more reference.

Be aware insert a Node at required position in linked list also need about `n/2` operation and is also `O(n)` and is as below:

```c
void insertPos(Node** current, int pos, int data)
{
    // This condition to check whether the
    // position given is valid or not.
    if (pos < 1 || pos > size + 1)
        cout << "Invalid position!" << endl;
    else {
 
        // Keep looping until the pos is zero
        while (pos--) {
 
            if (pos == 0) {
 
                // adding Node at required position
                Node* temp = getNode(data);
 
                // Making the new Node to point to
                // the old Node at the same position
                temp->next = *current;
 
                // Changing the pointer of the Node previous
                // to the old Node to point to the new Node
                *current = temp;
            }
            else
              // Assign double pointer variable to point to the
              // pointer pointing to the address of next Node
              current = &(*current)->next;
        }
        size++;
    }
}
```

Both of these two last algorithms need loop which means `o(n)`.

See [Insert a node at a specific position in a linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insert-a-node-at-a-specific-position-in-a-linked-list/) for more reference.